# How to interpret a collection when exporting to Excel (XLSX) using Telerik?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, telerik

### SCENARIO

---

I'm using the **[Telerik UI For Windows forms](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx)**.

I have a **[RadGridView](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/overview2)** on which I'm representing a custom type named `MarketInfo`:

```
Public NotInheritable Class MarketInfo

    ...
    Public ReadOnly Property Participants As ReadOnlyCollection(Of ParticipantInfo)
        Get
            Return Me.GetParticipants()
        End Get
    End Property
    ...

End Class
```

It just contains text and booleans properties, and the `Participants` property that returns a collection of another custom type:

```
Private Function GetParticipants(ByVal market As XElement) As ReadOnlyCollection(Of ParticipantInfo)
    Dim participantInfoList As New List(Of ParticipantInfo)
    For Each participantNode As XElement In market...<participant>
        participantInfoList.Add(New ParticipantInfo(participantNode))
    Next
    Return New ReadOnlyCollection(Of ParticipantInfo)(participantInfoList)
End Function
```

And this is the full `ParticipantInfo` class:

```
Public NotInheritable Class ParticipantInfo

    Private ReadOnly participantElement As XElement

    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return participantElement.@name
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Id As String
        Get
            Return participantElement.@id
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Odds As String
        Get
            Return participantElement.@odds
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property OddsDecimal As String
        Get
            Return participantElement.@oddsDecimal
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property LastUpdateDate As String
        Get
            Return participantElement.@lastUpdateDate
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property LastUpdateTime As String
        Get
            Return participantElement.@lastUpdateTime
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Handicap As String
        Get
            Return participantElement.@handicap
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal participantElement As XElement)
        Me.participantElement = participantElement
    End Sub

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

End Class
```

So basically I need to export a collection of `ParticipantInfo` type, that should be representable in Excel.

Well, so In the `RadGridView` I hide the column of the `Participants` because it can't represent it (because it's a collection), then I load that collection as datasource on another `RadGridView`.

To understand it better, this is the result:

[image]

### Problem

---

My problem is that I don't know how to interpret this in a excel file (XLSX).

This is the code with I'm trying to export the `MarketInfo` grid contents:

```
Dim exporter As New ExportToExcelML(rdg)
With exporter
    .HiddenColumnOption = HiddenOption.ExportAlways
    .HiddenRowOption = HiddenOption.ExportAlways
    .ExportVisualSettings = True
    .SheetMaxRows = ExcelMaxRows._65536
    .SheetName = "xxxxxxxx"
    .SummariesExportOption = SummariesOption.ExportAll
    .PagingExportOption = PagingExportOption.AllPages
    .FileExtension = ".xlsx"
    .RadGridViewToExport = rdg
    .ChildViewExportMode = ChildViewExportMode.ExportAllViews

End With

exporter.RunExport(fileName)
```

However, the generated file just contains the type name of the Participants:

```
...
<Data ss:Type="String">System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[WilliamHillLeecher.Leecher.Types.ParticipantInfo]</Data></Cell></Row>
...
```

[image]

I expected to see one Excel page created per each `MarketInfo` with those missing properties.

I'm not familiar with Excel usage and Excel terminology, I'm not sure how normally one can represent a collection in a sheet page, I suppose by creating a new sheet page and "linking" it to the corresponding cell.

I just would like to represent the same info in the Excel file that I represent in my application.

### Question

---

How I could do that with **Telerik** exporting related libraries?

In case it's not possibly to do using **Telerik** libs, then how I could do it with other 3rd party FREE library?.

( with this I'm just telling that I'm open to other kind of suggestions, however, please keep in mind that I'm aware of more focused Excel libraries, but anyways I'll still don't understand how to do this with any lib ...maybe due to missunderstanding of how can be done the same task of adding/representing a collection just using the Excel UI. )

Answer (score 3):

1. Populate a new RadGridView in memory **with the hierarchy** and export that as other people do it:
   http://www.telerik.com/forums/radgrid-hierarchy-export-to-excel-showing-exporting-master-table-rows-but-detail-rows-are-blank-lines
2. You could control what Excel XML is created using XML, [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) is really easy to work with compared to [OpenXML](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?q=OpenXML).
3. There are [loads of other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp) and
4. Opening a support request with Telerik might be the fastest way to confirm if there are any options for the Sheet Per Detail page in their [GridViewExportOptions](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/export/export).

Comment: Thanks for answer, the 4th suggestion is not possible since they dont will provide support for free user-accounts that elapsed the 30-days. I will try investigating the other options you suggested me and come here to accept the answer or expose here any barrier that I could encounter, because things still not really clear about how to represent the collection in a excel cell.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use opensource library, try this:
[EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/downloads/get/813458)
Once you reference the epplus.dll in your project the following code can export data to xlsx format the way you want:

```
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.Chart;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table;
using OfficeOpenXml.Table.PivotTable;

namespace OfficeOpenXml
{
    public static class ExcelHelper
    {

        public static void Save(dynamic Table, string path)
        {
            var excel = CreateReport(Table);
            excel.SaveAs(path);
        }
        static void Save(this ExcelPackage excel, string path)
        {
            excel.SaveAs(path);
        }
        static ExcelWorksheet Export(ExcelPackage excel, dynamic Table, out ExcelRange range) // here it is your grid
        {
            var sheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Master_Data");
            int row=0, col=0;
            foreach (dynamic dc in Table.Columns)
            {
                sheet.Cell(row, col++).Value = dc.Caption;
            }
            row++;
            col = 0;

            foreach (dynamic dr in Table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (object value in dr.ItemArray)
                {
                    sheet.Cell(row, col++).Value = value;
                }
                row++;
                col = 0;
            }
            range= sheet.Cells[0, 0, row - 1,  Table.Columns.Count - 1];
            return sheet;
        }

        static ExcelPackage CreateReport(dynamic Table)
        {
            var excel = new ExcelPackage();
            ExcelRange range;
            ExcelWorksheet sheet;
            sheet = Export( excel, Table, out range);

            CreatePivotTable(range, TableStyles.Medium12);
            return excel;
        }

        static ExcelPivotTable CreatePivotTable(ExcelRange range, TableStyles tableStyle)
        {
            int count = range.Worksheet.Workbook.Worksheets.Count;
            var summary = range.Worksheet.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("PivotTable" + count);
            var pivotTable = summary.PivotTables.Add(summary.Cells["A3"], range, "Summary" + count);

            pivotTable.ApplyBorderFormats = true;
            pivotTable.ApplyNumberFormats = true;

            pivotTable.TableStyle = tableStyle;

            pivotTable.WorkSheet.View.ShowGridLines = false;
            pivotTable.MultipleFieldFilters = false;
            pivotTable.RowGrandTotals = false;
            pivotTable.ColumGrandTotals = false;
            pivotTable.Compact = false;
            pivotTable.CompactData = false;
            pivotTable.GridDropZones = false;
            pivotTable.Outline = false;
            pivotTable.OutlineData = false;
            pivotTable.ShowError = true;
            pivotTable.ErrorCaption = "[error]";
            pivotTable.ShowHeaders = false;
            pivotTable.UseAutoFormatting = true;
            pivotTable.ApplyWidthHeightFormats = true;
            pivotTable.ShowDrill = true;
            //pivotTable.DataOnRows = false;
            pivotTable.WorkSheet.View.FreezePanes(pivotTable.PageFields.Count + pivotTable.ColumnFields.Count + 3, 1);


            foreach (var fld in pivotTable.Fields)
            {
                pivotTable.RowFields.Add(fld);
                fld.Compact = false;
                fld.Outline = false;
                fld.ShowAll = false;
                fld.SubtotalTop = false;
                fld.SubTotalFunctions = eSubTotalFunctions.None;
            }


            return pivotTable;
        }

    }
}
```

I have used dynamic keyword in some functions because I don't have any idea how data in your Telerik Grid is accessed but I guess it might have Rows and Columns properties. If this is not the case then you will have to change that part of code. If you are using DataTable as data source of the grid then you can pass the DataTable directly. Once a file is created, it can be opened with MS Excel or any other application which supports openxml format. you will have to play with ExcelPivotTable object in order to get the desired result.
Also see the screenshot of sample report below:
[image: Sample Report]

Comment: I appreciate your time, but this does not answer my question: "How to export/represent an Array of elements in a Excel file?". Seems that you're showing how to export a DataTable structure, I know many Excel libraries and I seen many examples to export like that, that is not what I need, I need a very specific example with an Array. Anyways I tried it but in the code you've provided "sheet" object is of "ExcelWorksheet" type,however,that type doesn't expose any "Cell" member,which you are using in the "Export" function,then on my side I get an compiler error because that member doesn't exists.

Comment: Sorry you are right. Cell(row,col) is an internal method to which I have access because I am using EPPlus source code. Since you are using dll, change sheet.Cell(row, col) to sheet.Cells[row, col] and it should work.

Comment: I have searched EPPlus samples and did not find anything of the sort. Maybe I am wrong but what you are asking can be accomplished using excel macros. Now using macros might raise security concerns but I don't see a way other than VBA function to expand details of selected Market Info object. I would suggest you to download EPPlus source code and find out a way to achieve what you want without using VBA macros.